# In TFS Online, How do I share a code branch with our customer

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We have an enterprise customer that we have delivered a system for. It is part of the agreement for us to supply them with the source code of the latest release. We are using TFVC on TFS online, and we thought it would be easiest to give them access to our Main branch. But I have difficulties with only allowing them to access the code and nothing else. The user I am testing with, can see too much: I.e. things like dashboard, current team members etc.

Is it possible for me to only expose code from the Main branch and nothing else to an external user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving access to TFS Main Branch out of Organization (AD) is not advisable considering security.. Instead consider giving source code into zip format there are lot of large file sending (FTP sites) are available..

Still for your request of restricting access to user have a look over this

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/restrict-access-tfs

you can consider replicating your part of source code into separate stream and give reader read only access to that stream.

Hope this helps... :)

Comment: Thanks @user7417866  What are your concerns with security related to giving access? If we can restrict access to only the code, then it will be the same as dumping the same content to an FTP server. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Considering TFS (Connected Environment) its not only 1 person who will have administration control, it might happens by mistake or human error if someone gives out permission to certain code branch, document, etc that may not mean for that customer... it might create loophole.. Considering FTP on other side will have disconnected environment from your organization and Client.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to these steps to set the permission:

1. Add user to your VSTS (Basic)
2. Remove this user from all group if you added
3. Go to admin page of a team project Version Control (Setting > Version Control)
4. Select a folder/branch
5. Click Add > Add User to add that user
6. Select the user that you added
7. Set Read permission to Allow
8. Go to Security page (click Security)
9. Click Create group to create a new group
10. Set View project-level information to Allow and deny other permissions for this group
11. Click Members of that new group
12. Click Add to add that user to this group

After that, this user can access the code (Just the folder/branch the user has the read permission) on web access (Code > Files).

Comment: I have already performed these steps, and my concern is that the user has access to dashboards, list of current team members, builds etc. and I have no overview over what he has access to.